# Add "what not to ask" to our FAQ

Tags: discussion

At the moment our "[What to ask](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)" FAQ page only lists what questions are on topic but doesn't really go into listing what we don't really want to see on our site. On the other hand sites, like Travel.SE have a [nice list](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) of the don't as well as the do's.

Should we add an off topic part to the FAQ site? If yes, what should we include there?

(also travel's FAQ also contains a nice disclaimer at the bottom, which might be useful on our site as well)

Answer (score 3):

Here is the FAQ, with some additional information merged in from the travel site:

Feel free to edit

> Expatriates Stack Exchange is for people living or intend to live abroad on a long-term basis, and for questions surrounding ordinary life, just complicated by your status as an expatriate.
>
> **If your question is about:**
>
> - Complications in every day life due to living in a foreign country as    a non-citizen
> - Questions about work, residence, student, investor and    similar mid and long term visas aimed for staying in the country for    more
>     time than a tourist or short term business visa would allow
> - Questions about permanent residence and nationality programs, as they    would apply to someone of your nationality living in, or
>     planning to move to a foreign country
> - Questions about what laws in your home country apply to you as an expatriate, and to what extent they apply
> - Questions about laws and governance in your country of residence, that might apply differently to non-citizens than they do to citizens Psychological and physical effects of the immigration to a different country, effects of weather, different culture and language Education and work seeking questions for a person migrating from a different country
>
> **and it's not about ...**
>
> - **Asking for the 'best' thing to do (or similarly subjective  questioning)**. Everyone is different. Detail what stuff you like to do/see if you're going down that route, so that we can better help you. **Subjective questions are VERY likely to get closed.**
> - General questions about living in a country, **which would similarly apply to a local citizen** and not just for expats. Please add specifics to the question that describes why you think your issue is specific because you are an expatriate, otherwise your question will likely be closed.
> - Questions about generic travel, tourism, and **short term** visits to a country, unless your current status as an expat would complicate or ease things (for example traveling to countries in the Schengen area while you're living inside it as an expatriate). For questions about travel please check [Travel Stack Exchange](https://travel.stackexchange.com/) instead.
>
> **... then you’re in the right place to ask your question!**
>
> Remember to be tolerant of others who may not have your experience, knowledge, political, cultural or social views, and be aware that some regions are in conflict and definitions in regards to these regions may be in a state of flux.
>
> While valid questions and constructive answers and comments are welcome, chatty messages or comments and especially political discussions should be reserved for our [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13567/the-embassy), and discussions about the site or questions should be on [meta](https://expatriates.meta.stackexchange.com/). If you feel there is any problem with a question, please flag it for a moderator.
>
> **Please look around to see if your question has been asked before.** It’s also OK [to ask and answer your own question](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/helpcenter/self-answer).
>
> If your question is not specifically on-topic for Expatriates Stack Exchange, it may be on topic for another Stack Exchange site. If no site currently exists that will accept your question, you may [commit to](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq) or [propose](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76974/how-can-i-propose-a-new-site) a new site at [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/), the place where new Stack Exchange communities are democratically created.
>
> For more help, see "[What types of questions should I avoid
>   asking?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)"